# Linear Transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anyone give a defined linear transformation in matrices that is preserving? Like if you apply the operation twice in a matrix then the result is the original matrix, i.e. $T(T(A))= A$.

Let $V_1$ and $V_2$ be vector spaces. A linear transformation is a function $T : V_1 → V_2$ with the following properties:

1. For any $v, w \in V_1$ we have $T(v + w) = T(v) + T(w)$.
2. For any $v \in V_1, r \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $T(rv) = rT(v)$.

Comment: Preserving what?

Comment: The question is not clear, but if $V_1$ is ${\bf R}^n$ and $V_2$ is ${\bf R}^m$ and $A$ is any $m\times n$ matrix then $T(v)=Av$ is a linear transformation.

Comment: Ah. Let $T(A)$ be the transpose of $A$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson that will only work if $T$ is defined as an endomorphism on square matrices, but it is an example for such a specific case.

Answer (score 3):

Well, first, the domain and codomain of $T$ will be the same. Then also: $T$ must be an isomorphism, and furthermore its own inverse. So there are many...here is an example: Let \begin{equation} T:\mathbb{F}_{m \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_{m \times n} \end{equation} be defined as \begin{equation} T(A)=I_{R_j \leftrightarrow R_i}A \end{equation} Where $I_{R_j \leftrightarrow R_i}$ is the $m \times m$ identity matrix with rows j and i exchanged. This transformation will exchange rows $j$ and $i$ in $A$, and is its own inverse.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple example is $T(A)=-A$. [An even simpler example is $T(A)=A$, but I'm assuming that's *too* simple. I'm also assuming you are working over the reals, or at any rate not over a field of characteristic 2, so my example is simple but not too simple.]